# Embedding R in C++: access elements of a VECSXP

Tags: r, visual-studio, rcpp

So I'm calling some R code from C++, and I'm calling directly into R.dll for that (I know about about Rcpp and I have the book here on my desk, but I can't use it for this specific thing). I have an R script that sets a variable and I want to access the contents of that variable.

The variable is a list of strings; in C++, when I do TYPEOF(my_sexp), I get VECSXP; so far so good. Now I want to read the contents of that list into a std::vector. I have tried many permutations of the following idea:

```
SEXP vector_exp = VECTOR_ELT(my_sexp, 0);
int element_count = TRUELENGTH(vector_exp);
for (int i = 0 ; i < element_count ; i++) {
    SEXP elem_sexp = VECTOR_ELT(my_sexp, i);
    std::string element_string = R_CHAR(elem_sexp);
}
```

My problems:
- Using TRUELENGTH, I can an access violation. Using LENGTH, I get a wrong value.
- Accessing elements of the list using VECTOR_ELT() causes an access violation.
- I've tried manually inspecting the memory layout of my_sexp according to the struct definitions in the R headers, but I can't seem to get the casting right to get a meaningful value from it.

So, is there anyone who can tell me roughly how to access the elements of a list; or point me to an example; or point me to the location in Rcpp where a conversion like this is done? I tried finding the last point myself, but didn't get far - it seems like Rcpp's wrap() handles it 'magically' (as in, generically) somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use Rcpp?

Comment: Or, even more obviously, [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) -- which does of course use [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, and I don't want a proxy dll in between for which the whole build would have to include a second toolchain.

Comment: Please [questions 1.3 and 2.9 in the Rcpp FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).

Comment: Right, which say that I can't use Visual Studio to use Rcpp - I took those two sections as the authoritative source to not even try to use RInside. Actually 2.9 says 'R and Visual Studio simply do not get along', which I guess is a typo and should say 'Rcpp and Visual Studio simply do not get along', because I'm now calling directly into R.dll from Visual Studio code which is working fine. I'm hoping though that now that MS has invested big in R, that they'll spend some manpower on fixing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't spent very much time working with R's C interface, as I usually stick to Rcpp, but the following seems to work:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void print_list_as_vector(SEXP lst) {
  PROTECT(lst);
  R_xlen_t n_list = XLENGTH(lst);
  R_xlen_t n_elem = 0;

  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n_list; i++) {
    n_elem += XLENGTH(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i));
  }

  std::vector<std::string> vs;
  vs.reserve(n_elem);
  for (R_xlen_t i = 0; i < n_list; i++) {
    R_xlen_t nj = XLENGTH(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i));
    for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < nj; j++) {
      vs.push_back(CHAR(STRING_ELT(VECTOR_ELT(lst, i), j)));
    }
  }

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < vs.size(); i++) {
    Rcpp::Rcout <<
      vs[i] << std::endl;
  }

  UNPROTECT(1);
}

/*** R

clist <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("l", "m", "n", "o", "p"), c("xyz1", "xyz2"))

print_list_as_vector(clist)
#a
#b
#c
#l
#m
#n
#o
#p
#xyz1
#xyz2

unlist(clist)
# [1] "a"    "b"    "c"    "l"    "m"    "n"    "o"    "p"    "xyz1" "xyz2"
*/
```

---

This was tested within R / using Rcpp attributes as you can see, but in the actual meat of code I tried to stick to the C interface to replicate your situation.

But to address your questions (as best I can) -

1. I have always used `XLENGTH` to get the length of `SEXP`s, and although I can't really speak to the differences between `XLENGTH`, `LENGTH` and `TRUELENGTH`, the first method always seems to produce the expected result.
2. I'm using `VECTOR_ELT(lst, i)` to access the ith element in the `VECSXP` `lst`.
3. Given the context of the data / function, I know that `VECTOR_ELT(lst, i)` is returning a `STRSXP` - i.e. a character vector. The jth element of this `STRSXP` is accessed with `STRING_ELT(..., j)`, and since this returns a `CHARSXP`, we wrap it in `CHAR` to get a `const char*`, which is added to the `std::vector<std::string>`.

---

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be *that* much documentation for R's C internals, but Hadley has a useful [reference page here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html), and if all else fails, you can dig through [the source itself](https://github.com/wch/r-source).

Comment: Thank you, this has been very helpful. I'll just have to figure out what the difference is between the various length functions you mention, because I've used Rf_length() up until now and that seems to work, too. Either way, it turns out that my real problem was that there weren't really CHARSXP's in my list as I thought, but rather LANGSXP's; so what I had to do, was wrap the assignment of the variable in my R script with capture.output: result <- capture.output(summary(fit)) (where 'fit' is the result of glm()).